# Update/Save list item edits without closing editform

Tags: javascript, client-object-model

I am working with a customised list 'editform' and would like to give my users the ability to save their edits without the editform closing, which is the default SP 'Save' behaviour.

I have linked the following code to a HTML button on my form, which appears to be going through the saving motions but refreshing the underlying list shows that the edits made were not saved.

```
function updateListItem() {

var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext($url);
var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Manage Recruitment Process Tasks');

this.oListItem = oList.getItemById($myID);

oListItem.set_item('Advertisement_x0020_Date', $adDate.val());

oListItem.update();

clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
}

function onQuerySucceeded() {

alert('Item updated!');
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {

alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

The variable $url is set to '/sites/dev' and the variable $myID is set to the list item ID.  The code is getting through to 'oListItem.update();' but no further, without the onQuerySucceeded() or onQueryFailed() functions triggering.

Is there a syntax error in the code?

Thanks

Simon

Comment: You can check the browser console window for any error. In IE it is called developer toolbar. In IE and Chrome browser you can hit F12 and it will bring the developer toolbar and you can check in "Console" window.

Comment: The above code worked fine for me. Check $adDate.val(). I used var currentTime = new Date(); and then used oListItem.set_item('Advertisement_x0020_Date', currentTime); Alos, check whether the internal name of the field is correct.

Comment: I think for date you need to have UTC date/time, check this: http://alexeybbb.blogspot.in/2012/09/sharepoint15-js-update-datetime-field.html